# Automatically displaying VCS annotations in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to have IntelliJ IDEA automatically display Git / VCS annotations in the left margin *for every file that I open*?  Right now, I can bring them up by right-clicking in the left margin and choosing `Annotate` or by using the `VCS -> Git -> Annotate` menu option.  Both of these options are cumbersome when I want to view annotations for dozens of files in a row.

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 12.1.3.

Answer (score 23):

I found that by using the keyboard path it was pretty straight forward.
{ALT + S} > g > n - will display the annotations, but I wanted a faster way.

So i created a shortcut.
File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > VCS > GIT > right click annotate and 'add keyboard shortcut' - I used {Ctrl + Alt + z} since that didn't conflict with any I already had.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 16):

I was searching for the same feature for a while, but couldn't find in **intellij 13.0**.

So I ended up adding up shortcut(`Ctrl Alt 0`) through `File->Settings->keymap`, which will show or hide the **VCS annotation**.

[image: intellj vcs annotation]

Comment: image is helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think it cant be done by default. Note that the "annotate" feature executed every time will cause a huge overload in the system that most of the people prefer to avoid.

Comment: I would not think it would be significant if it happened on file load.